# FrameLayout's margin bottom for child doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-framelayout

I have the following view hierarchy:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
       <!-- Some Child views-->
   </LinearLayout>
   <ImageView>
   </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried to set the bottom margin of the `ImageView` and on the layout editor it seems to be working, but when I run the code the bottom margin I set it's discarded.

Important note: I also defined `margin top` to the `ImageView` and it **does** work.

I saw other questions and **I already tried** to set the `gravity` of the `FrameLayout` child views to `top` but that doesn't work also.

I also saw that this issue is resolved for Android > 3.0 (I'm running on 4) - [Link to the issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28057)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always wrap your `ImageView` into a `FrameLayout` and set the desired bottom margin from the `ImageView` as bottom padding for the wrapper `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
       <!-- Some Child views-->
   </LinearLayout>
   <FrameLayout // same attributes as the ImageView but with also android:paddingBottom="xxdp">
       <ImageView // no margin set here!>
       </ImageView>
   </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And if you say this behavior was fixed starting with Honeycomb then you could use API dependent layout folders, my layout for below Honeycomb and your layout for any other API level.

Comment: I meant that although I'm using Android version > 3 it still doesn't work. I tried your solution but the given layout is of a list item so adding an extra layout manager for each row affects noticeably on the performance.

Comment: @Daniel And why do you need the bottom margin on the `ImageView` if you're going to stack it on top of the `LinearLayout`(to which I hope you're not giving a top margin to fit the two pieces)?

Comment: Because I want it to cover only a certain part on the `LinearLayout` and no, I'm not setting a top margin to the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Daniel Please post your layout file with the attributes you're using.

Comment: Omg! Your answer saved my life! I was misled into setting the gravity of the layouts, while your solution was so simple and concise. Thank you.